# Where is data stored in OpenEBS?

Tags: openebs

Setup -- OPENEBS version 0.6
I would like to know where OpenEBS stores data in Jiva.
Where does it exactly store the data? Does  it store locally on Kubernetes nodes mount path or on a disk attached to the pool.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the storage pool which is referred to in the storageclass. 
If the pool is "default" and the storage engine chosen is Jiva, then the storage space for volume replica data is carved out from the container image space of the replica pod itself ("/mnt/openebs_disk").

---

apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
   name: openebs-standard
   annotations:
    cas.openebs.io/config: |
      - name: ControllerImage
        value: openebs/jiva:0.7.0-RC2
      - name: ReplicaImage
        value: openebs/jiva:0.7.0-RC2
      - name: VolumeMonitorImage
        value: openebs/m-exporter:0.7.0-RC2
      - name: ReplicaCount
        value: "1"
      - name: StoragePool
        value: default
      - name: FSType
        value: "xfs"

If the storage pool referred to in the storageclass is NOT "default", then it will be an external disk or group of disks that are mounted at a given path inside the replica pod